# Displaying information to the user after page processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, controls

I'm (very) new to ASP.NET and am building a registration form. I built an empty web site, added `Register.aspx` and populated it with all the form elements that're usually presented on a registration page. I also made the form submit to the Register.aspx page.

Now, I want to catch the POST data after it's submitted. I saw there was a `Page_Load` method in Register.aspx.cs, and within that I've done:

```
if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
{
    // Validate inputs and show information to the user
}
```

But now I have no idea how I can print things to the page. After some digging I tried to use a Label control, so I put this on my Register.aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

but when I try to access it using `StatusLabel.Text` from within Register.aspx.cs I get an error saying it doesn't exist in the current context.

I'm thoroughly confused, how can I achieve what I want to do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you declaration of

```
<asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

is within the page content, i.e. inside of the

```
<asp:Content></asp:Content>
```

tags

Comment: Are you seeing a Default.aspx.designer.cs file underneath Default.aspx?  If not, then right click Default.aspx and do 'Convert to Web Application"

Comment: Your code sample in Pastebin is showing its CodeFile is Default.aspx.cs (line 1).  You need to change that to Register.aspx.cs.  You should then be able to put a breakpoint in your Page_Load event to verify it is being fired.